# How to find out whether file is being used?

Tags: file, sockets, ipc

Specifically, how can I find out whether file created by AF_UNIX socket is in use or just left lying around from the previous run of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to determine whether file is being used by connecting to it. If connect fails, there's no listening socket associated with the file.